# Perform exact function in timer tick after a specific time

Tags: c#, timer

I'm working on a project in which I'm working with my serial ports.
When I open my serial port after that I'll have to send 4 requests. SO for sending request my code is:

```
private string ByteArrayToHexString(byte[] data)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(data.Length * 3);
            foreach (byte b in data)
                sb.Append(Convert.ToString(b, 16).PadLeft(2, '0').PadRight(3, ' '));
            return sb.ToString().ToUpper();
        }

        private void senddata1(String str)
        {

                // Convert the user's string of hex digits (ex: B4 CA E2) to a byte array
                byte[] data = HexStringToByteArray(str);

                // Send the binary data out the port
                comport.Write(data, 0, data.Length);



        }
```

This function will create a method to send data. 
On timer tick event I'm sending this Data:

```
 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
//here I'm sending my data in a timer
 senddata1(s1);
 senddata1(s2);
 senddata1(s3);
 senddata1(s4);

}
```

**Note:after every senddata1() function system will get a response.**

So the problem is When I'm sending data I'm not getting the response because system is unable to read all senddata.
I want to manage my program in a way so that I can send data after every 250 second.
Like this:

```
SendData1(s1);
get response from the system
senddata1(s2);
get response from the system
```

get response is being handled in like this:

```
   comport.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);
```

So is there a way I can manage my program.
Please share your opinions.

Comment: Clearly you don't *really* like the DataReceived event since you want to block your code until the response is received.  So don't use it, just call Read() directly.  Don't forget to loop until you got the entire response.

Comment: @HansPassant, Thanks that can help me, as I'm new in serial port programming, Can you please tell me a brief or some example.

Answer (score 0):

If you means that you want to call senddata1 function on system response, you should use an event to aware you on responses.
Then call senddata1 with the indicated input (s1, s2, ...) that should bee given to the function on each response.

*(And let me know if I didn't realize what you asked. Tell in comment)*

Comment: I have tried this but there is a slight problem that I'm unable to track the response. It's being managed like a delegate. So is there a way to check whether I got the output.